# Компиляция less в css через webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, less

Господа!

Это сервер

```
    var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
app.listen(8888);
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('/print', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    res.send();
});
```

Это package.json

```
    {
  "name": "mizami",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "**********************************",
  "main": "serv.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node serv",
    "test": "webpack -w --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "******************************************"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "short",
    "advertising",
    "site"
  ],
  "author": "**************************************",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "************************************",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

Это файл webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./serv",
    node: {
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
              {loader: "css-loader"},
              {
                  loader: "less-loader",
                  options: {
                      includePaths: ["./less/", "./public/css/"]
                  }
              },
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("main.css"),
  ]
};
```

Запуск в console gitbash: webpack -w --config webpack.config.js
 Вопрос:  запускаться запускается, но файл css не создает и не работает, в чем у меня ошибка, помогите....  Заранее спасибо!!!

Файл less у меня в корне, а css должен создаться в public/css/main.css

И еще вопрос: я должен запускать и

- npm start
  и
- npm test  ?

Или можно одной командой обойтись?

Забыл добавить вот что выдает в консоли
[image: при команде webpack -w --config webpack.config.js]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить отдельно js файл отдельно css файл нужно использовать плагин [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

Как-то так будет:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
              {loader: "css-loader"},
              {
                  loader: "less-loader",
                  options: {
                      includePaths: ["./less/", "./public/css/"]
                  }
              },
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ]
```

Comment: Если не трудно объясни поподробнее,  по твоему примеру не получилось ничего...  ошибок не показывает, но файл css не создает.  Он я обновлю вопрос, посмотри как я запускаю и правильно ли я делаю?

Comment: @Air я не вижу ошибок, попробуйте убрать `includePaths`

Comment: @Air проверьте, попадают ли стили в бандл вообще

Answer (score 1):

Свой ответ пишу, если вдруг кому то понадобиться...

```
    var path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./less/main.less", // путь откуда берет less
    node: {
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public/css",  // путь куда вставлять компилированный css 
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: ["css-loader", "less-loader"]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [

    new ExtractTextPlugin({
     filename: 'main.css'  // а тут надо прописать имя css которое вы хотите 
    })
  ]
};
```

существенный  вклад -- Igor Golovin

Answer (score 0):

Так он и не должен css создавать. Весь css-код оказывается где-то внутри js и там при необходимости вставляется в dom.

Comment: Когда мне доводилось связываться с вебпаком, он мне css-файлы таки создавал. Правда, формат его конфига я уже давно забыл и хз че конкретно тут

Comment: @andreymal, вроде в соседнем ответе вариант конфига?